# Code running in Netbeans but not in command line

Tags: java, netbeans

I downloaded the time series classification toolbox available [here](https://bitbucket.org/TonyBagnall/time-series-classification/downloads/) that I succeed to run with Netbeans (not with Eclipse due to compatibility problems) using the command

```
netbeans --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/
```

I would like to be able to run it on a server so I need to be able to run it using command lines.
However I didn't succeed. My guess is that there is a problem with jdk (I'm not used to Java so it might be something else), since when I run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

I get

```
There are 5 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1091      auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gij-4.8                                 1048      manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/gij-4.9                                 1049      manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/gij-5                                   1050      manual mode
* 4            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
  5            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1091      manual mode
```

Which does not contains the path to the jdk I use with Netbeans.
I didn't find a way to tell Java that I wanted to use another jdk, so I tried without:

---

**Example where I run a specific main file**

From `TimeSeriesClassification/src`:

```
javac timeseriesweka/classifiers/LearnShapelets.java 
java -cp ../bin:. timeseriesweka.classifiers.LearnShapelets
```

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TechnicalInformation
>
> at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>
> at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>
> at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
>
> at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
>
> at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
>
> at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
>
> at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TechnicalInformation
>
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>
> ... 7 more

Any help on how to set up correctly Java will be appreciated

---

With (following the answer of ACV)

```
java -cp ../bin/Test.jar:lib/*:. timeseriesweka.classifiers.LearnShapelets

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory
    at timeseriesweka.classifiers.LearnShapelets.main(LearnShapelets.java:746)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`-cp "../bin/Test.jar:lib/*:."` instead of your:

`-cp ../bin:.`

Comment: Got a different error:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory
 at timeseriesweka.classifiers.LearnShapelets.main(LearnShapelets.java:746)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory
 / Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory
(I'll had the full error in the question)

Comment: That's a Java 9 class. So you need java 9 to run that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.html

Comment: `javac -version` returns: `javac 9-internal` whereas `java -version` returns `openjdk version "1.8.0_151"` So if I understand well I just need to update my JDK version?

Comment: You need both to be the same java 9